# Does CSS accept 'pixel' in decimals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pixel

I was going through jQuery functions.

Lets take this as an example:

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

If you do 'Inspect Element' on your browser, you can see the height of the div changing. The height takes decimal values of pixels. How to do that with javaScript?

Comment: How about just trying it to see?  Also, [please be careful with w3schools](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: @POinty, Thats okay! I am not talking about w3schools here. PLease help me with my doubt!

Comment: I have done it lot's of times, i don't think it actually works tho?

Comment: @Connor, How jQuery does it then?

Comment: When you say "in decimals", do you mean values like "100.23"?  Just use such values directly in calls to `.css()`, `.width()`, etc.

Comment: well, what are you trying to do? $('#something').css('height', '101.55px'); should work, also please check my profile description about W3Schools

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't look things up on W3Schools, they are a bad source.  In general, when you want to know something like this, just look at [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units).  Lengths are `<number>`s, which can include fractional values.

Comment: Although, I'm not sure how can you divide one pixel of the screen in two?

Comment: A pixel in CSS doesn't necessarily equal one physical screen pixel.  It's a lot more complicated than that, involving viewing distances, etc.

Comment: @drinchev If you express everything in half pixels, then scale the page up by 2, they become whole pixels! :o

Comment: @eugen_sunic, W3Schools are not the W3C.  They chose a similar name that tricks people into thinking that they have something to do with the W3C, but they are an entirely unrelated organisation.

Comment: @Jim OMG, I didn't know that! Tnx for revealing

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like this:

```
<script>
function auto(){
    var obj=document.getElementById("d");
    var height=parseFloat(obj.style.height);
    obj.style.height=height-10+'px';
}
```

```
<button value="change" onclick="auto()"></button>
<div id="d" style="border:thick solid black;width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
```